# How can I exclude sub-dependencies from unmanaged dependencies?

Tags: sbt

I know in sbt you can do something like this to exclude specific sub-dependencies of dependencies for some lib your project uses:

```
  val kafka        = "org.apache.kafka"    %  "kafka-clients"        % "0.9.0.1" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx")
  )
```

How can I do this for an unmanaged jar?  I put an unmanaged library jar 'something.jar' in my project's lib directory but sbt is giving me errors for some dependencies of something.jar that I don't care about.  How can I exclude these?

Comment: Unmanaged jars do not have transitive dependencies. What you are describing is not required